# Java unsafe memory allocation limit

Tags: java

Does Java sun `Unsafe.allocateMemory` has any limitation? I know that it's off heap so it's not subject to GC. But can we limit allocation size by JVM command like :

```
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Unsafe#allocateMemory](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#l481) method is native, and the [native implementation of Unsafe#allocateMemory](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/190899198332/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp#l583) directly calls [os::malloc](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/hs-dev/hotspot/file/787c9c28311f/src/share/vm/runtime/os.cpp#l570), delegating the work for the allocation to the underlying system. There is some bookkeeping and some debugging options, but it seems that there is no built-in mechanism for limiting the allocation size.

Depending on the application case, you might consider wrapping the `Unsafe#allocateMemory` call into an own method, that does a check for a size limit based on a command line parameter, as you suggested.

If your intention was to prevent a third party library (that uses `Unsafe#allocateMemory` internally) from allocating too much memory, I think there will be no reasonable way to achieve this.

Comment: Is there any official doc about the mechanism how the allocation size is controlled for `Usnafe#allocateMemory`