# Why XX:MaxDirectMemorySize can't limit Unsafe.allocateMemory?

Tags: java, memory-management

The code below will allocate a large size of direct memory but do not cause *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory* :

```
//JVM args: -Xms10m -Xmx10m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10m
    public class DirectMemoryOOM {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
            Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredFields()[0];
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Unsafe us = (Unsafe) f.get(null);
            long size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
            while (true) {
                long p = us.allocateMemory(size);
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    us.putByte(p + i, Byte.MAX_VALUE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the code following code will get *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory*.
I have seen the answer from [Java unsafe memory allocation limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670700/java-unsafe-memory-allocation-limit), but ByteBuffer.allocateDirect is implemented using Unsafe.allocateMemory()

```
//JVM args: -Xms10m -Xmx10m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10m
public class DirectMemoryOOM {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        int size = 1024 * 1024;
        System.out.println(sun.misc.VM.maxDirectMemory());
        while (true) {
            ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size);
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the limit fail happens to the first one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the original answer says: `Unsafe.allocateMemory()` is a wrapper around `os::malloc` which doesn't care about any memory limits imposed by the VM.

`ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` will call this method but before that, it will call `Bits.reserveMemory()` (In my version of Java 7: `DirectByteBuffer.java:123`) which checks the memory usage of the process and throws the exception which you mention.

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from `Bits.reserveMemory` which is called before the `unsafe.allocateMemory(size)` when calling `allocateDirect`.

The `reserveMemory` method procceed this validation :

```
synchronized (Bits.class) {
    if (totalCapacity + cap > maxMemory)
        throw new OutOfMemoryError("Direct buffer memory");
    reservedMemory += size;
    totalCapacity += cap;
    count++;
}
```

The error is thrown if the desired allocation is higher then the `maxMemory` retrieved from

```
maxMemory = VM.maxDirectMemory();
```

Calling `allocateMemory` directly will proceed native method and won't validate the max capacity (that explain why you don't get the error in your first snippet) which is the main goal of the `--XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` as explained in this comment in `reserveMemory`

```
// -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize limits the total capacity rather than the
// actual memory usage, which will differ when buffers are page
// aligned.
if (cap <= maxMemory - totalCapacity) {
     reservedMemory += size;
     totalCapacity += cap;
     count++;
     return;
}
```

---

Worth to mention that your first snippet implementation is not a good practice. A comment in `Bits.java` specify that `reserveMemory` should always be called whenever direct memory is allocated :

```
// These methods should be called whenever direct memory is allocated or
// freed.  They allow the user to control the amount of direct memory
// which a process may access.  All sizes are specified in bytes.
static void reserveMemory(long size, int cap) {
```